# Startup image - splashscreen

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Here is my app code

```
Ext.application({

    {...}

    isIconPrecomposed: false,
    name: 'CarboZero',
    startupImage: {
        '320x460': 'resources/startup/splashscreen.png',
        '640x920': 'resources/startup/splashscreen.png',
        '640x1096': 'resources/startup/splashscreen.png',
        '768x1004': 'resources/startup/splashscreen.png',
        '748x1024': 'resources/startup/splashscreen.png',
        '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/splashscreen.png',
        '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/splashscreen.png'
    },

    launch: function() {

        Ext.create('CarboZero.view.InitView', {fullscreen: true});
    }

});
```

When it lauches in IOS simulator, it still shows the sencha logo startup image... why? Do I need to do something more to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to edit your index.html file? Theoretically it should eliminate the splash screen. Here's how I did it:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html manifest="" lang="en-US">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>YourApp title</title> 
  <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
  <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="touch/microloader/development.js">   
 </script>
  </head>
 <body>
  </body>
 </html>
```

`

Comment: The fact is I want a splash screen, it's simply that I want our splash screen and not sencha's. Do I need to add something to index.html for that?

Comment: I suppose so..since by default the splash screen is in the index.html file it shouldn't be a problem modifying it. Also make sure to check your styling in the app.scss file. Let me know where this goes. Good Luck!